# Router blocks traffic because no D flag

Tags: internet, router

Not sure if it is the right place to ask the question..

I have a following issue

On my desktop computer I can't access internet. Precisely, i can't ping router.
However I can ping other machines on local network and i'm getting IP from DHCP located on the same router.

In router log messages I found 
"Saturday November 21, 2009 14:10:07 Block MY_MAC-AB-A3-5E because no D flag"

I failed to find anything interesting in google.

Any ideas? (How make desktop add D flag to packets or stop router blocking traffic)

Desktop is running on Windows XP
arp -a says that machine doesn't now MAC of router, however setting it to be static doesn't help either. 
Router is D-Link DI-524
I used to have internet on that machine, it stooped working recently, however i can't thing of anything that could cause that.

Comment: you right SO is not the correct place for your question, place in on serverfault.com

Comment: Try doing a factory reset of the router, and then try again.